# Can't get slanger to start as an Upstart service

Tags: server, upstart, services

I have created the file `/etc/init/slanger.conf` and I'm trying to get it to start as a service.

The following are the contents of the file

```
start on started networking and runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]
respawn
script
    LANG=en_US.UTF-8 /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/slanger --app_key <MY_API_KEY> --secret <MY_SECRET_PASSWORD> --redis_address redis://<MY_SECRECT_REDIS_URL>:6379
end script
```

When I try to run `sudo service slanger start` I get the following output:

```
slanger start/running, process 2039
```

But it's not really running because when I do `sudo service slanger status` I get:

```
slanger stop/waiting
```

And when I run `ps -ef |grep slanger` I can see that there is no such service running:

```
ubuntu    2092  1903  0 15:09 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto slanger
```

I don't know what I am missing here. Please point me in the right direction

Comment: Look at the other scripts in `/init`, you might have to `emit` a `started` event.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new service:
`sudo nano slanger.service` in  /etc/systemd/system$

```
[Unit]
Description=Slanger Server

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/usr/local/bin/slanger
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/slanger --app_key 123 --secret 123

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=slanger.service
```

Use those to start and stop:

```
sudo service slanger start
sudo service slanger status
```

If need to change slanger path:
which slanger